# How to select only the last match using sed?

Tags: bash, sed, grep, find, match

I want to extract the diagonal numbers of this tensor:

```
 *********** Symmetrised Stress Tensor ***********
 *                                               *
 *          Cartesian components (GPa)           *
 * --------------------------------------------- *
 *             x             y             z     *
 *                                               *
 *  x      3.832865      0.000000      0.000000  *
 *  y      0.000000      3.832865      0.000000  *
 *  z      0.000000      0.000000      3.922869  *
 *                                               *
 *  Pressure:   -3.8629                          *
 *                                               *
 *************************************************
```

For this purpose I tried the following

```
sed -n 's/.*\* *x *\([0-9.-]*\).*/\1/p' file1 >> x_component.txt
```

However, since there are several of these tensors, this gives me all possible matches in file1. And I only want the last match (only the x-component of the last tensor).

Desired output is:

```
3.832865
```

in file x-component.txt

```
3.832865
```

in file y-component.txt, etc

Comment: Mmm the file is super complex. It's not a simple table of data. So I'm not quite sure if it is necessarily that way. I'm gonna put more of the file to give a better context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to use sed?

```
awk '$1 == "*" && $2 == "x" {v=$3} END {print v}' input
```

If you must use sed, it's probably easier just to pipe it to a 2nd instance which prints only the last line:

```
< input sed -n '/^\* *x */s///p' | sed -n '$s/ .*//p'
```

(Cheating a bit here, making some simplifying assumptions and using the second sed to get only the first column.)

Comment: It's pretty straightforward awk.  If the 1st and 2nd columns of the line match `*` and `x`, respectively, then the variable v is assigned the value in the 3rd column.  After input is exhausted, the value of v is printed.

Comment: if instead of having the final match I wanted the penultimate one, how could I achieve that?

Comment: Now that the question has changed so dramatically, I would recommend a completely different approach.  In general, to get the penultimate sample, a quick hack is something like `awk '...{a=b; b=$0} END {print a}'`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^\s*\*\s*x\s*(\S+).*/{s//\1/;h};$!d;x' file
```

Store the `x` value in the hold space and swap to the hold space at end of file.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of Williams post.
Instead of printing the latest found, print the one with number in position `3`

```
awk '$1=="*" && $2=="x" && $3~/[[:digit:]]/ {print $3}' file
3.832865
```

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't print the last match. It prints all the matches from all the tensors. As I explain in the question there are several of these tensors, so several matches for "*  x"